# dominance coefficient, why (1+k)?

Tags: quantitative-genetics

I'm trying to get a better understanding of quantitative genetics by reading [Lynch and Hill 1986](http://www.indiana.edu/~lynchlab/PDF/Lynch27.pdf). I'm getting stuck with some notation that's used right at the beginning referring to the mutant and WT alleles at a given loci.

2*a<sub>i</sub>* is the genotypic value for WT homozygous 
(*k*+1)*a*<sub>i</sub> is the genotypic value of the F1 heterozygous

 0 genotypic value for the non-existent "mutant" homozygous

From my understanding, *a* is the additive genetic effect and *k* is the dominance coefficient. I understand that 2*a<sub>i</sub>* is the additive genetic effect at this particular loci which moves this trait away from the population mean for this trait.

Can someone explain the (1+*k*)? I understand that there could be dominance between the new and old allele, but I don't understand why 1 needs to be added to the dominance coefficient.

Comment: Without digging into the paper to be sure, it seems to just be a definitional thing.  Including the "+1"  would allow the dominance coefficient (k) to scale between -1 for perfectly recessive to +1 for perfectly dominant.